# Jquery UI draggable doesn't resize other DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Vb9a4Keky2r5zOTtVLS?p=preview) I have three `DIV`s divided by two other `DIV`s that are draggable (gray color). When the draggable `DIV`s are dragged up/down or left/right, the other `DIV`s should be resized.

The first draggable DIV works fine (the one on the left that resizes the other DIVs vertically). But the second draggable `DIV` doesn't work, even though the method is the same as the first draggable `DIV`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Javascript

```
    var top1H, bottom1H;
      $( "#div1" ).draggable({
          axis: "y",
          start: function(event, ui) {
            shiftInitial = ui.position.top;
              top1H = $("#top1").height();
              bottom1H = $("#bottom1").height();
            },
          drag: function(event,ui) {
              var shift = ui.position.top;
              $("#top1").height(top1H + shift - shiftInitial);
              $("#bottom1").height(bottom1H - shift + shiftInitial);
            }
        });

    var right1W, left1W;
  $( "#div2" ).draggable({
          axis: "y",
          start: function(event, ui) {
            shiftInitial = ui.position.left;
              right1W = $("#right1").height();
              left1W = $("#left1").height();
            },
          drag: function(event,ui) {
              var shift = ui.position.left;
              $("#right1").height(right1W + shift - shiftInitial);
              $("#left1").height(left1W - shift + shiftInitial);
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="left1">
    <div id="top1"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="bottom1"></div>
  </div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
   <div id="right1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 { 
  width:180px;
  height:6px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  cursor:ns-resize;
  position: absolute;
}
#div2{
  width:6px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  float:left;
  cursor:ew-resize;
}
#top1{
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
#bottom1 {
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#left1{
  width:180px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  background-color:orange;
}
#right1{
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you first dragable `DIV` works fine I fixed only the second one.

There are two problems with your code:

1. You gave both draggable elements the `axis: "y"` attribute (while the second should be grad on `X` axis.
2. The change on the second drag was supposed to be on the width (and not on the height).

```js
$(function() {
        var top1H, bottom1H;
        var right1W, left1W;
        
        $( "#div1" ).draggable({
            axis: "y",
            start: function(event, ui) {
                shiftInitial = ui.position.top;
                top1H = $("#top1").height();
                bottom1H = $("#bottom1").height();
            },
            drag: function(event,ui) {
                var shift = ui.position.top;
                $("#top1").height(top1H + shift - shiftInitial);
                $("#bottom1").height(bottom1H - shift + shiftInitial);
            }
        });
        $( "#div2" ).draggable({
            axis: "x",
            start: function(event, ui) {
                shiftInitial = ui.position.left;
                right1W = $("#right1").width();
                left1W = $("#left1").width();
            },
            drag: function(event,ui) {
                var shift = ui.position.left;
                $("#left1 div").width(left1W + shift);
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
#div1 { 
  width:180px;
  height:6px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  cursor:ns-resize;
  position: absolute;
}
#div2{
  width:6px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  float:left;
  cursor:ew-resize;
  left: 180px;
}
#top1{
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
#bottom1 {
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#left1{
  width:0;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  background-color:orange;
}
#right1{
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="left1">
    <div id="top1"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="bottom1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="right1"></div>
</div>
```

> Note that the code will **NOT** work if you drag the borders "outside" of the current block. To do so you will also need to check if the new width/height is bigger than the original and change all the elements accordingly.

### Update - allow change the height of the "red" box

(It's better to view this in "full page" mode)

```js
$(function() {
  var minHeight = $('#right1').height();
  var top1H, bottom1H;
  var right1W, left1W;

  $( "#div1" ).draggable({
    axis: "y",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      shiftInitial = ui.position.top;
      top1H = $("#top1").height();
      bottom1H = $("#bottom1").height();
    },
    drag: function(event,ui) {
      var shift = ui.position.top;
      $("#top1").height(top1H + shift - shiftInitial);
      $("#bottom1").height(bottom1H - shift + shiftInitial);
      $('#right1,#div2').height(Math.max(
        minHeight,
        Math.max(
          $('#top1').height()+$('#div1').height(),
          $('#top1').height()+$('#bottom1').height()
        )));
    }
  });
  $( "#div2" ).draggable({
    axis: "x",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      shiftInitial = ui.position.left;
      right1W = $("#right1").width();
      left1W = $("#left1").width();
    },
    drag: function(event,ui) {
      var shift = ui.position.left;
      //$("#right1").width(right1W - shift + shiftInitial);
      $("#left1 div").width(left1W + shift);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 { 
  width:180px;
  height:6px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  cursor:ns-resize;
  position: absolute;
}
#div2{
  width:6px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  float:left;
  cursor:ew-resize;
  left: 180px;
}
#top1{
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
#bottom1 {
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#left1{
  width:0;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  background-color:orange;
}
#right1{
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="left1">
    <div id="top1"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="bottom1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="right1"></div>
</div>
```

> This version will not give you the option to "lower" the height of your blocks once the height changed.

Comment: what do you mean by "change all the elements accordingly" ?

Comment: If you drag the horizontal border and make the height of the orange box bigger than the height of the red box - the red box height will not change.

Comment: @ps0604, do you need the code to support that too? Because in your original question it wasn't mentioned. Did you check my answer?

Comment: If you can provide the complete answer that would be great. Since you already answered the question, I accepted your answer.

Comment: Added another example there.