# Resize multiple divs to keep layout correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a layout similar to JSFiddle's layout, aka a resizable grid. You can see it in the code snippet below or in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/72xhr1wr/1/).

```js
$("#left").resizable({
  alsoResize: "#right",
  handles: "e"
});

$("#right").resizable({
  alsoResize: "#left",
  handles: "w"
});

$("#text").resizable({
  handles: "s"
});

$("#css").resizable({
  handles: "s"
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
}
.section#text {
  clear: both;
  height: 20vh;
}
.section#css {
  clear: both;
  height: 30vh;
}
.section#animation {
  clear: both;
  height: 50vh;
}
.section#result {
  height: 100vh;
}
.section.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="left" class="section container">
  <div id="text" class="section"></div>
  <div id="css" class="section"></div>
  <div id="animation" class="section"></div>
</div>
<div id="right" class="section container">
  <div id="result" class="section"></div>
</div>
```

To be able to resize the `div` elements I am using the `jQueryUI` function [resizeable](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/). However, if you play with the code example, you will see that the grid is not contained to the initial screen size. Instead, the `div` elements can be resized into each other and off the screen.

As you will see in the code example using methods such as [alsoResize](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize) don't work. I have also attempted to use methods such as [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-containment) but that does not seem to help either.

I would appreciate any help in making this work properly

Comment: Maybe check sourcecode for fiddle :)

Comment: The resizable is not exactly what you are looking for, but you can use my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289204/jquery-ui-draggable-doesnt-resize-other-divs/38553541#38553541 It can give you a hint of how to solve this.

Comment: @Dekel This is great. Thank you

Comment: Sure. You are welcome to upvote my answer there if it helped you :)