# how to drag a div to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 vertical div's and I want the users to be able to resize the div from the bottom corner.

The following code dose not working so good

```js
var isResizing = false,
    lastDownX = 0;

$(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
        bottom = $('#bottom_panel'),
        top = $('#top_panel'),
        handle = $('#drag');

    handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
        lastDownX = e.clientY;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
        if (!isResizing) 
            return;
        
        var offsetTop = container.height() - (e.clientY - container.offset().top);

        bottom.css('top', offsetTop);
        top.css('height', offsetTop);
    }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        // stop resizing
        isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
}

#bottom_panel {
 position:relative;
 background: grey;
 width:100%;
 height:70vh;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#top_panel {
 width: 100%;
 height:30vh;
 color:#fff;
 background: black;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#drag {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 right:0;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
 top: -4px;
 width: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
 width:10px;
 height:20px;
 background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
 <div id="top_panel">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 </div>
 <div id="bottom_panel"> 
  <div id="drag"></div> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't code everything in one line!

Comment: you can check it in codepen @Endless :)   http://codepen.io/spooler/pen/JKgvWj

Comment: thanks please check it

Comment: Wouldn't just pure css be an option? way more simpler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: no no i want to similar this fiddle but vertical : http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/82/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI draggable doesn't resize other DIVs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289204/jquery-ui-draggable-doesnt-resize-other-divs)

Comment: @Dekel yes its good but how to set minimum ax maximum height?

Comment: Try to use the solution from there using css's  max-height, or check the height during the drag and if the height is more than your max, dont continue the dragging

Comment: can you write code in codepen?

Comment: i now using max-height and min-height in css but not working good please help me

Comment: @OmidOmidparkour, Add the code you tried using my solution from the duplicate question, I'll try to have a look.

Comment: @Dekel i try with any way but not working can you write code in codepen?

Comment: Post a link to what you did so far

Comment: i want to similar this fiddle but vertical : jsfiddle.net/T4St6/82